# YUM command issues

Tags: yum

I was trying to install a package on my yum respository earlier using the command:

```
https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/compat-openmpi16-1.6.4-10.7.2.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

For some reason when I run for example:

```
yum search gfortran
```

I get the following message:

```
yum search gfortran
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
created by dnf config-manager from https://cent 6.9 kB/s | 5.8 kB     00:00    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'centos.pkgs.org_7_centos-x86_64_compat-openmpi16-1.6.4-10.7.2.el7.x86_64.rpm':
  - Status code: 403 for https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/compat-openmpi16-1.6.4-10.7.2.el7.x86_64.rpm/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 46.4.72.43)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'centos.pkgs.org_7_centos-x86_64_compat-openmpi16-1.6.4-10.7.2.el7.x86_64.rpm': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

What can I do to resolve this issue and restore yum capabilities?

I says that rpm packages mentioned in the error message are not there.  Please help me resolve this situation.

Comment: Can you confirm your OS version?

Comment: Clear `yum` cache and try again

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing directly from URL. For eg. `yum install https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/compat-openmpi16-1.6.4-10.7.2.el7.x86_64.rpm`